# Error running cucumber tests - no such file to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, cucumber

I have a rails app with Cucumber 1.0.0 and cucumber-rails 1.0.2. These tests ran fine last night. Today I just altered some step definitions and tried to run the tests and got the error below. I haven't changed anything in the cucumber support files. Any ideas?

```
grouperty $ cucumber
Using the default profile...
no such file to load -- /Users/davidtuite/wd/grouperty/features/config/environment(LoadError)
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/davidtuite/wd/grouperty/features/support/env.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@grouperty/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
/Users/davidtuite/wd/grouperty/features/support/env.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@grouperty/gems/cucumber-1.0.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load'
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@grouperty/gems/cucumber-1.0.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load_code_file'
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@grouperty/gems/cucumber-1.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:176:in `load_file'
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@grouperty/gems/cucumber-1.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:78:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@grouperty/gems/cucumber-1.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:77:in `each'
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@grouperty/gems/cucumber-1.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:77:in `load_files!'
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@grouperty/gems/cucumber-1.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:137:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@grouperty/gems/cucumber-1.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:39:in `run!'
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@grouperty/gems/cucumber-1.0.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@grouperty/gems/cucumber-1.0.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@grouperty/gems/cucumber-1.0.0/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@grouperty/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
```

/Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@grouperty/bin/cucumber:19:in `'

Here is the content of `/features/support/env.rb`. Note that most of it was generated by the spork gem (v0.9.0.rc9).

```
# IMPORTANT: This file is generated by cucumber-rails - edit at your own peril.
# It is recommended to regenerate this file in the future when you upgrade to a 
# newer version of cucumber-rails. Consider adding your own code to a new file 
# instead of editing this one. Cucumber will automatically load all features/**/*.rb
# files.

require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'cucumber/rails'

  # Capybara defaults to XPath selectors rather than Webrat's default of CSS3. In
  # order to ease the transition to Capybara we set the default here. If you'd
  # prefer to use XPath just remove this line and adjust any selectors in your
  # steps to use the XPath syntax.
  Capybara.default_selector = :css

end

Spork.each_run do
  # By default, any exception happening in your Rails application will bubble up
  # to Cucumber so that your scenario will fail. This is a different from how 
  # your application behaves in the production environment, where an error page will 
  # be rendered instead.
  #
  # Sometimes we want to override this default behaviour and allow Rails to rescue
  # exceptions and display an error page (just like when the app is running in production).
  # Typical scenarios where you want to do this is when you test your error pages.
  # There are two ways to allow Rails to rescue exceptions:
  #
  # 1) Tag your scenario (or feature) with @allow-rescue
  #
  # 2) Set the value below to true. Beware that doing this globally is not
  # recommended as it will mask a lot of errors for you!
  #
  ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

  # Remove/comment out the lines below if your app doesn't have a database.
  # For some databases (like MongoDB and CouchDB) you may need to use :truncation instead.
  begin
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  rescue NameError
    raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
  end

  # You may also want to configure DatabaseCleaner to use different strategies for certain features and scenarios.
  # See the DatabaseCleaner documentation for details. Example:
  #
  #   Before('@no-txn,@selenium,@culerity,@celerity,@javascript') do
  #     DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[widgets]}
  #   end
  #
  #   Before('~@no-txn', '~@selenium', '~@culerity', '~@celerity', '~@javascript') do
  #     DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  #   end
  #
end
```

Comment: please post `/Users/davidtuite/wd/grouperty/features/support/env.rb` code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this line

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
```

requires

```
/Users/davidtuite/wd/grouperty/features/config/environment
```

which is not present there this causes error

Comment: Obvious once you say it! Thanks.